# Scipy.optimize.minimize ignores the bounds

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

Below is the dummy example, for which I expect the answer 0.8, but it outputs something close to 0:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds
minimize(lambda chi: chi**2, 1, method='nelder-mead',  bounds=Bounds(0.8,1.2,True) )
```

Comment: This method does not support bounds.["multidimensional **unconstrained** optimization without derivatives"](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nelder-Mead_algorithm)

Comment: @sascha this seems not to be the issue, as constraints are a separate parameter. Anyway, if I run the same thing with COBYLA optimizer (constrained), the result is still not within the bounds

Comment: It is the issue. Cobyla might not support it too (only ineq-constraints if i remember correctly). Try it with something actually supporting it, like `method="L-BFGS-B"` and be amazed ;-) **Edit** and read the docs on how to pass the initial point -> hint: `1 -> [1]`

Comment: Indeed, L-BFGS-B works. Thanks

Comment: However, the Powell method does not respect the bounds, but it should according to the documentation